# How to Migrate files having path in it?

Tags: 7, migrations

I have a custom table in drupal 6 in which file path is stored in the field like `sites/default/files/file_name.jpg`. I dont have `fid` for this field.

How can I map this with my image field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the file in `prepareRow()` and map the fid with my field.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image', 'fid');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image:file_class')
  ->defaultValue('MigrateFileFid');
```

In my prepareRow method :

```
  public function prepareRow($row) {
    if (parent::prepareRow($row) === FALSE) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    $files_dir = '/mnt/files';
    $file_name = str_replace('sites/default/files/', '', $row->image);
    $file_path = $files_dir . $file_name;
    $row->fid = _my_migration_upload_file($file_path);
    return TRUE;
  }
```